# "Destination Port Unreachable" only on secondary IP of VM

Tags: linux-networking, ip, vmware-vsphere, ping, ipv4

An vmware VM is assigned two IPs. We can only ping one of the two IPs from VMs on the same network.

```
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:98:87:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.233.0.2/16 brd 10.233.255.255 scope global ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.233.0.3/16 brd 10.233.255.255 scope global secondary ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe98:87db/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Source is 10.233.15.102 and the test shows 10.233.0.2 is pingable but 10.233.0.3 is not.

```
$ ping 10.233.0.3
PING 10.233.0.3 (10.233.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.233.0.3 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 10.233.0.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 10.233.0.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable

$ ping 10.233.0.2
PING 10.233.0.2 (10.233.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.502 ms
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.155 ms
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
```

When source is 10.233.14.102 the test shows that both 10.233.0.2 and 10.233.0.3 are pingable.

```
$ ping 10.233.0.2
PING 10.233.0.2 (10.233.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.223 ms
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms

$ ping 10.233.0.2
PING 10.233.0.2 (10.233.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.233.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.252 ms
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I've extensively used multiple IP addresses per vNIC without problems. Are you sure neither the local firewall (iptables) nor the network (switch ACL) is filtering? Does the ARP table get populated?

Comment: @Zac67 Yes they did get populated with wrong MAC addresses. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there was a kubernetes cluster that was using the same range 10.233.0.0/24 for its internal network. This caused the arp tables to get populated with their MAC addresses.